# Where to find trusted root certificates on every OS to satisfy mbedtls?

Tags: c++, c, mbedtls, certificate-store, root-certificate

I'm writing a cross platform websocket client using mbedtls. Now I'm left with the burden of feeding a suitable pack of trustet root certificates to the mbedtls API [which looks like this](https://x509errors.org/guides/mbedtls):

```
/* Structure to load trusted root certs into. */
mbedtls_x509_crt ca_certs;
mbedtls_x509_crt_init(&ca_certs);

/* Parse the file with root certificates. */
if (mbedtls_x509_crt_parse_file(&ca_certs, "trusted_certs.pem") != 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Set the certificates as trusted for this session. */
mbedtls_ssl_conf_ca_chain(&conf, &ca_certs, NULL);
```

It's pretty straightforward, I just need to concatenate all found certificates and feed it into the function.

- I know that on my embedded system (esp32) which is also using
  mbedtls, there's already a library that provides me with the
  system-wide CA store, so that should be no problem.
- On linux systems I know that the certificate bundle will mostly
  reside under `/etc/ssl/certs`. Question: Is this true for every
  (major) distribution?
- On Windows I frankly have no idea. There seems to be something like a certificate store, but how do I get my certificates out of there?
- On Apple I don't really care (yet) <3

A reference codebase would also be very helpful!

Comment: Look at what existing programs do. Curl, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Look at GnuTLS for an example of how this can be achieved. Specifically, look at *add_system_trust()* in *~\gnutls\lib\system\certs.c*

For Windows it boils down to calling CertOpenStore() and loop through the certificates using CertEnumCertificatesInStore() and CertEnumCRLsInStore() then close the store using CertCloseStore() - very simple.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumcertificatesinstore